# How to repair a hard drive file system used for Samsung smart tv

Tags: hard-drive

I'm having a problem with my hard drive I use for my Samsung smart tv. Apparently it is a known problem, as the Samsung D-model TVs sometimes ruins the hard drivers file system, so I found a guide online on how to repair it.

I had to get ubuntu and plug in the hard drive. I should have received an error message saying something like "Cannot mount the driver I/O error", but I didn't.

After this I should write the command "sudo xfs_repair -L /dev/sdc" (I also tried with sdc1) in Terminal. I did that, and got the message "Phase 1 find and verify superblock..bad primary superblock - bad magic number !!! attempting to find secondary superblock...sorry could not find valid secondary superblock. Exiting now."

I tried searching online for different things to do. I tried the following commands: 
sudo fdisk -l
--> giving me:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107835392 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773116 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd5f0e851

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048   976769023   488383488    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc
```

I also tried:

```
sudo badblocks /dev/sdc
```

--> it gave me:

```
1024
1025
1026
1027
```

And I tried:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdc
```

--> it gave me:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdc
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

I'm a very inexperienced linux user and I have no idea what is wrong or how to fix it. I do NOT want to format my hard drive as I have important files on there. 
I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

The `fdisk` output says that it is an NTFS file system:

```
/dev/sdc1            2048   976769023   488383488    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

So you don't need linux to correct it, you need windows and run `chkdsk /f` on the drive. `xfs_repair` is for the XFS file system and `fsck` is for most of the linux native file systems. Linux doesn't have proper tools to fix an NTFS file system, since NTFS is not linux native, but Microsoft's proprietary file system.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fix the **NTFS** partition under Linux, please have a look at the manpage of [ntfsfix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/ntfsfix.8.html) and decide for yourself.

I've never used it and can't give any recommendation.

Comment: `ntfsfix` is not a replacement for Windows `chkdsk` unfortunately.  Windows' utilities are probably one of the best approaches for fixing issues in the `ntfs` filesystem.